# Arrayaccess and native php array functions

Tags: php, arrays, arrayaccess

Is there any way to use `array_merge()`, `array_pop()`, .. functions to work with ArrayAccess?

Since now i've tried `Iterate` interface and `__set_state()` magic method with no success.

Error that is given: `array_replace_recursive() [<a href='function.array-replace-recursive'>function.array-replace-recursive</a>]: Argument #1 is not an array`.

Just fo a record, `gettype()` returns `object` and `is_array()` returns `false` and i'm usin php version 5.3.8

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Unfortunately, no. They only work with the native array type. You have to add those as methods to your object's public API and implement them there, e.g. something like this:

```
class YourClass implements ArrayAccess, Countable
{
    public function pop()
    {
        $lastOffset = $this->count() - 1;
        $lastElement = $this->offsetGet($lastOffset);
        $this->offsetUnset($lastOffset);

        return $lastElement;
    }

    public function mergeArray(array $array) {
        // implement the logic you want
    }

    // other code …
}
```

Comment: Thought so, but just in case asked. Ty

Comment: I don't understand this answer - are you saying that I would need to implement `array_merge` and other native array functions as methods of my `ArrayAccess`-implementing class?

Comment: @alexw yes, because these functions expect arrays for input. A class implementing ArrayAccess is not the same type as an array.

Comment: Think of specifying "array" type as a test of "instance of array" - and ArrayAccess is not an "instance" of array, obviously... for now... it would be awesome if you could replace that, since you could leverage so many things during the input, e.g. stream output when using `exec()` etc...